# Jersey not loading index.html

Tags: java, html, spring, jersey

I am having some difficulty loading an index.html with the way my project is set up - my structure looks as follows;

[image]

My web.xml looks as follows;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">

    <module-name>restprj</module-name>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>SpringApplication</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
            <param-value>com.rest.test.demo.MyApplication</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>SpringApplication</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/service/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

I can call my rest end points with no issue - for example

http://localhost:8080/service/entry-point/test2/hi

this gives me output - however if i navigate to the url http://localhost:8080/service/ i get a 404 - it makes no difference where i place my index.html - is anyone able to point out what im doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are placing `index.html` in the `/target` folder, use the `src/main/webapp` folder for all your `.js` and `.html` files. Target folder will be cleaned up every time you `mvn clean install` and they will not be included in your packaging, ever.

After you make the changes, build the project, copy the war to a certain location, rename the .war to .zip, extract the contents and see if it contains the index.html file in the root folder. You may do this before and after the changes I suggested to understand how and where the index.html is packaged to.

Comment: navigating directly to http://localhost:8080/index.html actually displays the page now! should it not display when i navigate to http://localhost:8080/service though?